# /dev/mapper/ un--app02--vg-root space reducing

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm

I am very new to ubuntu. My Ubuntu server is hosting our central Unify wifi management software. But I have received a message un-app02: Free disk space on / is less than 20%. I am attaching a screen shot which shows the remaining space. How can I solve the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30xfl.jpg)

Best Regards,

Nafis

Comment: Please post the text, not a screenshot of text

Comment: /dev/mapper/un--app02-vg-root  (used space is 83%)

Comment: I do not understand the question - what part of "almost out of storage space" do you need help with? Are you asking what it means? Are you asking how to find the biggest space users? (Hint: That's been asked before - use the Search box) Are you asking how to add more space on another drive?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have managed to get space by  cleaning up some cache and also by deleting some more files which was up´loaded from our server.